# Check for consecutive numbers in filenames [BASH]

Tags: bash, multidimensional-array, error-checking

With a regular interval files ending on a number arriving in three different directories. (file format = filename_number.mxf) 
The script that i've come up with strips the numbers of the last four files
and place them into a variable. This script will be executed by *incrond*

```
for bier in $(ls -tr *.mxf | tail -n -4)
do
file="${bier#*_}"
base=${file%.*}
echo $base
done;
```

But how can i test this on consecutiveness across three directories
and tell in which directory this occured?
(in the example below the file with number 20117 in *dir2* did not arrived, 
when this happens i want to raise a warning/trigger)

This should be reported as correct:

```
<dir1>   <dir2>   <dir3>
20114    20114    20114
20115    20115    20115
20116    20116    20116
20117    20117    20117
```

And this should be reported as incorrect:
(files in dir2 is one file behind the rest)

```
<dir1>   <dir2>   <dir3>
20114    20113    20114
20115    20114    20115
20116    20115    20116
20117    20116    20117
```

Comment: use find and it gives the full path.

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Then either use `find` to operate on all the files at once or use different loops per-directory and collate at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this will help

```
$ f() { ls -tr $1/*.mxf | tail -n -4 | xargs -n1 basename; }; 
  cmp --silent <(f dir1) <(f dir2) && cmp --silent <(f dir2) <(f dir3);
  echo $?

1
```